# Issue using Intel C++ compiler 16, update 3, in 32 bit

Tags: c++, debugging, shared-ptr, 32bit-64bit, icc

I was wondering if someone faced the same problem I found yesterday. I use ICC 16 (Intel C++ compiler 16.0, update 3) on VS 2015. I build in 32 bits. **Note that this problem doesn't occur in 64 bits.**

Assume the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

void func( shared_ptr<int> p )
{
    if ( p == nullptr )
    {
        cout << "nullptr" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "! nullptr" << endl;
    }
}

//----------------------------------

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    shared_ptr<int> i = nullptr;
    // cout << "Hello!" << endl;
    func( nullptr );

    return 0;
}
```

This code works properly and output "nullptr".

But if I uncomment `cout "Hello!"<<endl;`, the `shared_ptr<int> p` passed as argument to `func(...)` is invalid, so it is not equal to nullptr (saw in `if{}else{}`) and there is a crash when exiting the function because the destructor (of the `shared_ptr<int>`) cannot be executed properly.

Note again that this doesn't occur when compiling in 64 bits. In 64 bits, it always runs correctly. The bug occurs only in 32 bits.

I tried a lot of build parameters but I could not find one suspect. Has someone faced the same bug?

Also, I know that there is an update 4 for ICC 16 (but I failed to download it so far). Does this update solve this problem?

Any help will be appreciated!

**EDIT 1**

I corrected the call to `func(nullptr)`. Actually I have to write `nullptr` directly in the ( ), not passing an automatic variable.

Comment: For the sake of completeness can you show the code in its entirety -- with `#include` and `using namespace` statements etc.

Comment: @G.M. Done. I added the #includes and the using namespace std;.